# Setting up another server at another address

Tags: server, webserver, nameserver

Im not really that knowledgeable in servers and set-ups, but have my own dedicated server that runs my business website.

Currently both name servers of my domain are the same server, which I intent to change, because if the current NS goes down, my website becomes unreachable.
Am I right about having more NS' from different people, the less chance my website will be unreachable?

And also the A record for my domain points to my servers IP address which is all good and works apart from when the hoovering needs to be done then i get unplugged and go down. so what i'm after is updating the domain and adding anther A record so if my server gets unplugged or goes down the back up server will kick in at a different place or address.

Am I correct in saying that I can add more name servers from different companies and more A records that points to different servers?

Comment: You are talking about two things. First, as a web hosts in my previous life, it was required at that time that all domain names use two NS servers on separate networks. As a web host, I used two networks and NS servers that were not my own for my domain name and two networks and NS servers for my customers and my own domain name that were my own. This provided redundancy. As well, having several servers can be referenced using more than one A record. This is called round-robin references. This works well. However, is it far better to use a proxy or router for load-balancing and fail-over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding additional A records will cause [round robin DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS).   It will not act as a backup.   Rather some of your visitors will see one server, and some will the other.   If either of your servers go down, your site will be unavailable to half your visitors.

When you get a second dedicated machine, ask for a load balancer between the two.  Load balancers work the way you want.   You can take a machine offline for maintenance.  The load balancer monitors the machines, detects that one is down and shifts all the requests over to the other.